# ASP.NET Core's asp-append-version attribute not working for static files outside of the wwwroot directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, wwwroot, asp-append-version

I have an ASP.NET Core project with static files in both the `wwwroot` directory and `bower_components` directory.

I am able to server these files by adding this to my `Startup.cs` class:

```
StaticFileOptions rootFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions();
rootFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse = staticFilesResponseHandler;
StaticFileOptions bowerFileOptions = new StaticFileOptions();
bowerFileOptions.OnPrepareResponse = staticFilesResponseHandler;
string bowerDirectory = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "bower_components");
PhysicalFileProvider bowerPhysicalFileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(bowerDirectory);
bowerFileOptions.FileProvider = bowerPhysicalFileProvider;
bowerFileOptions.RequestPath = new PathString("/bower");
app.UseStaticFiles(rootFileOptions);
app.UseStaticFiles(bowerFileOptions);
```

And then reference them from my views as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Libs/jQuery-UI/jquery-ui.min.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
```

Even though `asp-append-version` seems to work just fine for resources located under `wwwroot`, it seems to be completely ignored for resources outside of `wwwroot`. All resources are being properly served though; no 404s or anything. The resulting HTML for the code above is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Libs/jQuery-UI/jquery-ui.min.js?v=YZKMNaPD9FY0wb12QiluqhIOWFhZXnjgiRJoxErwvwI"></script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can generate version directly using extension AddFileVersionToPath from [How does javascript version (asp-append-version) work in ASP.NET Core MVC](//stackoverflow.com/a/45088852)

Answer (score 9):

This question is old, but the issue still exists and although the solution provided by Artak works, it is conceptually incorrect in most cases. First let's see the root of the problem:

`asp-append-version` looks for the files using `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider` which by default is a `PhysicalFileProvider` pointing to the `wwwroot` folder.

The Core docs have an example on how to [serve files outside of web root](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#serve-files-inside-of-web-root):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles(); // For the wwwroot folder

    app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
    {
        FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
            Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "MyStaticFiles")),
        RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
    });
}
```

This allows you to server static files from both `wwwroot` and `MyStaticFiles` folders. If you have an image `\MyStaticFiles\pic1.jpg`, you can refer to it in two ways:

```
<img src="~/pic1.jpg" />
<img src="~/StaticFiles/pic1.jpg" />
```

Both will work equally. This is conceptually incorrect because you gave the path an alias of `/StaticFiles`, so its files shouldn't be combined with the root `/`. But at least it works and it gives you what you want.

Sadly, `asp-append-version` doesn't know about all of that. It should, but it doesn't. It should because it is meant to be used with static files (JavaScript, CSS, and images), so it makes sense that if we changed the configurations to serve static files from different folders, that `asp-append-version` gets a copy of those configurations. It doesn't, so we need to configure it separately by modify `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider`.

Artak suggested to use `CompositeFileProvider` which allows us to assign more than one file provider to `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider`. That does work, however it has a fundamental issue. `CompositeFileProvider` doesn't allow us to define the `RequestPath` like in `StaticFileOptions`. As a workaround, Artak suggested that we should not use the prefix, which makes use of the above mentioned incorrect behaviour that files can be referenced in both ways. To demonstrate the issue, let's say that the other folder has a structure like this:

```
|_ MyStaticFiles
       |_ HTML
       | |_ privacy.html
       | |_ faq.html
       |_ images
         |_ image1.jpg
```

Now, what happens to all files in the `MyStaticFiles\images` folder? Assuming that `wwwroot` also has `images` folder, will it work or give you an error for two identically named folders? Where will the file `~/images/image1.jpg` be coming from?

Regardless of whether it works or not, there is often an important reason for why you have your static files in a folder other than `wwwroot`. It is often because those static files are for example content files that you don't want mixed with website design files.

We need a provider that allows us to specify the `RequestPath` for each folder. Since Core doesn't currently have such provider, we're only left with the option of writing our own. Although not difficult, it's not a task that many programmers like to tackle. Here is a quick implementation, it's not perfect, but it does the job. It is based on the [example provided by Marius Zkochanowski](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7459#issuecomment-372138482) with some inhancements:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

namespace Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders {
  class CompositeFileWithOptionsProvider : IFileProvider {
    private readonly IFileProvider _webRootFileProvider;
    private readonly IEnumerable<StaticFileOptions> _staticFileOptions;

    public CompositeFileWithOptionsProvider(IFileProvider webRootFileProvider, params StaticFileOptions[] staticFileOptions)
  : this(webRootFileProvider, (IEnumerable<StaticFileOptions>)staticFileOptions) { }

    public CompositeFileWithOptionsProvider(IFileProvider webRootFileProvider, IEnumerable<StaticFileOptions> staticFileOptions) {
      _webRootFileProvider = webRootFileProvider ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(webRootFileProvider));
      _staticFileOptions = staticFileOptions;
    }

    public IDirectoryContents GetDirectoryContents(string subpath) {
      var provider = GetFileProvider(subpath, out string outpath);
      return provider.GetDirectoryContents(outpath);
    }

    public IFileInfo GetFileInfo(string subpath) {
      var provider = GetFileProvider(subpath, out string outpath);
      return provider.GetFileInfo(outpath);
    }

    public IChangeToken Watch(string filter) {
      var provider = GetFileProvider(filter, out string outpath);
      return provider.Watch(outpath);
    }

    private IFileProvider GetFileProvider(string path, out string outpath) {
      outpath = path;
      var fileProviders = _staticFileOptions;
      if (fileProviders != null) {
        foreach (var item in fileProviders) {
          if (path.StartsWith(item.RequestPath, StringComparison.Ordinal)) {
            outpath = path.Substring(item.RequestPath.Value.Length, path.Length - item.RequestPath.Value.Length);
            return item.FileProvider;
          }
        }
      }
      return _webRootFileProvider;
    }
  }
}
```

Now we can update Artak's example to use the new provider:

```
app.UseStaticFiles(); //For the wwwroot folder.
//This serves static files from the given folder similar to IIS virtual directory.
var options = new StaticFileOptions {
  FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(Configuration.GetValue<string>("ContentPath")),
  RequestPath = "/Content"
};
//This is required for asp-append-version (it needs to know where to find the file to hash it).
env.WebRootFileProvider = new CompositeFileWithOptionsProvider(env.WebRootFileProvider, options);
app.UseStaticFiles(options); //For any folders other than wwwroot.
```

Here, I'm getting the path from the configurations file, because often it is even outside the app's folder altogether. Now you can reference your content files using `/Content` and not `~/`. Example:

```
<img src="~/Content/images/pic1.jpg" asp-append-version="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider removing the `/bower/` prefix when referring to `jquery/dist/jquery.min.js` as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Also, you should set the `HostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider` in the `Startup.Configure` method as follows:

```
var compositeProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(
    env.WebRootFileProvider,
    new PhysicalFileProvider(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "bower_components")));
env.WebRootFileProvider = compositeProvider;
var options = new StaticFileOptions()
{
    FileProvider = compositeProvider,
    RequestPath = "/bower"
};
app.UseStaticFiles(options);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Artak, this solution makes it work, but it's not ideal. Combining different folders with `wwwroot` and pretend that all static files are coming from the root is conceptually incorrect. The correct way to do it for the majority of cases is to like IIS does it with virtual directories, it adds them to the root. So files coming from `wwwroot` will be served from `/` and files coming from other folders (`bower_components` in OP case) will be served from the assigned names under root (`/bower` in OP case).

Comment: `CompositeFileProvider` doesn't allow that, so another provider should be added which accepts `StaticFileOptions` (or similar). I know that implementing such a provider is relatively easy, but I think it's a basic functionality that should be part of Core. People shouldn't have to remove the prefix (`/bower` in OP case) to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing. [According to ASP.NET Core's source](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/c27b07ef3f8b07dfe1d1de38a8d7bf2d6a9298f4/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers/ScriptTagHelper.cs#L392), they create a `FileVersionProvider` which starts from the `WebRootPath` or `wwwroot` for this task:

```
private void EnsureFileVersionProvider()
{
    if (_fileVersionProvider == null)
    {
        _fileVersionProvider = new FileVersionProvider(
            HostingEnvironment.WebRootFileProvider,
            Cache,
            ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.PathBase);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looking at code it seems everything related to that FileVersionProvider is private. I don't know a lot about tag helpers: is there any way to inherit and extend original tag helper? Or extend this particular behavior somehow? Thanks

Comment: I think it's a very good behavior. because it forces you to bundle your static files and then apply a version to that single file. you should not have a direct reference to the `bower` or `node_js` folders. Use https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier for this task.

Comment: I agree with examples you provided, but let me dissent in general. We have a separate angular-cli client project (same for any webpack-based one) which *compiles* and bundles its own sources into classic `dist` folder. There's no way we're going to use BundleMinifier, and I'm not sure we should save client build output into asp.net `wwwroot` folder.

Comment: why not? set the `outDir` in `.angular-cli.json` to `wwwroot` and then use this solution: http://michaco.net/blog/Angular4GettingHashedWebpackBundlesWorkingInASPNETCoreMVC

Comment: Yeah I am aware you can. I'm just not sure we should. I'll have a thought about it. Thanks for pointing to that post, though.